# How to click a link and open it in a new tab geckodriver selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a webelement `cells[-1]` I'm trying to click and open it in a new tab, then download something from a link on that page then close it and return to the original tab.

I have used

`actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(cells[-1]).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element = cells[-1]
href = element.get_attribute("href") 
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get(href)
```

Comment: Thanks man this would have worked great however the site will not allow any links to open in new tabs :(